# Rails 2.3.12 writes csrf token to session that it is not asked for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't use `protect_from_forgery` in my application controller, and on my development environment it works as expected, no session is generated. But on production environment the CSRF token is written to the session.

`Session.inspect` gives

```
{:_csrf_token => "duY6ATHEBzYXzg8aXdNF6CZYXicPhlFQdDodjREMwAM=",
 :session_id => "25728f624574a1d831b4510b2e7f6c92"}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in one partial I have

```
<% form_tag session_path, :method => :post do -%>
```

and it writes _csrf_token to session.